# MySQL Interval Variables And Subquery Notation

Tags: mysql, variables, subquery

I inherited this MySQL query as a bit of legacy code:

```
       SELECT
        HardwareAddress, CONV(SUBSTRING(EventValue,3,2), 16, 10) AS 'Algorithm'
        FROM ( SELECT @prev := '') init
        JOIN
            ( SELECT HardwareAddress != @prev AS first,
                @prev := HardwareAddress,
                HardwareAddress, EventValue, ID
                FROM Events   
                    WHERE Time > {unixtime}
                    AND EventType = 104
                    AND HardwareAddress IN ({disps})
                    ORDER BY
                        HardwareAddress,
                        ID DESC
            ) x
       WHERE first;
```

`{unixtime}` and `{disps}` are variables that are filled with the Python String.format() method.

I'm having a hard time creating new functionality out of this query because no one else understands how it works, and I haven't been able to find adequate documentation. All I know is that the query pulls a list of values called 'algorithm' from a long hex string sent by IoT devices.

I roughly understand how the subselect and the interval variables are working, but there is a lot I don't understand. How does the `FROM (SELECT @prev := '') init` line work? The last two lines of the query also confound me. Why is the subquery aliased to `x` when nothing is referencing it, and what on earth does the `WHERE first` mean?

If someone is able to walk me through what this bit of code is doing, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: It is an inefficient way to find the first row per group.

Comment: Can you show a better way of doing it? I'd still like to understand how the above code works. Because it does work.

Comment: In your case probably a UNION ALL solution would be the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break the SQL into parts.  The guts of the whole is the JOINed subquery:

```
SELECT
  HardwareAddress != @prev AS first,
  @prev := HardwareAddress,
  HardwareAddress,
  EventValue,
  ID
FROM Events
WHERE
    Time > {unixtime}
AND EventType = 104
AND HardwareAddress IN ({disps})
ORDER BY HardwareAddress, ID DESC
```

1. Column 1: Not knowing (yet) what `@prev` is, we see the operator is `!=`.  That means that whatever its operands are, column 1 will be a binary value.  In MySQL, a `1` or a `0`.
2. Column 2: Sets a SQL variable, `@prev`, to the value of the currently matched row.  Discussion below, but the result as far as the query goes will always be `NULL`.
3. Columns 3, 4, 5: I assume self explanatory.
4. Constraints 1, 2, 3: I assume self explanatory.
5. ORDER BY: of note is that the query orders the results by the 3rd column `HardwareAddress`, and then `ID` *descending*.

The first column then is a boolean, saying if the `HardwareAddress` column of this row is the same as that of the previous row.  In context, 1 means that this is the first row of that `HardwareAddress`, given the `ORDER BY`.

So, the query will return a result like:

```
+-------+--------------------------+-------------------+------------+-----+
| first | @prev := HardwareAddress | HardwareAddress   | EventValue | ID  |
+-------+--------------------------+-------------------+------------+-----+
|     1 |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:5f:f5:01 | ...        |  10 |
|     0 |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:5f:f5:01 | ...        |   9 |
|     0 |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:5f:f5:01 | ...        |   8 |
|     0 |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:5f:f5:01 | ...        |   7 |
|     1 |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:5f:f5:02 | ...        | 200 |
|     0 |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:5f:f5:02 | ...        |  37 |
|     0 |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:5f:f5:02 | ...        |  24 |
|     0 |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:5f:f5:02 | ...        |  23 |
|     0 |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:5f:f5:02 | ...        |  22 |
|     1 |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:5f:f5:03 | ...        | 152 |
|   ... |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:..:..:.. | ...        | ... |
|   ... |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:..:..:.. | ...        | ... |
|   ... |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:..:..:.. | ...        | ... |
+-----+----------------------------+-------------------+------------+-----+
```

Putting it together with the constraint of the outer query, `WHERE first`, and the final result would be:

```
+-------+--------------------------+-------------------+------------+-----+
| first | @prev := HardwareAddress | HardwareAddress   | EventValue | ID  |
+-------+--------------------------+-------------------+------------+-----+
|     1 |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:5f:f5:01 | ...        |  10 |
|     1 |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:5f:f5:02 | ...        | 200 |
|     1 |                     NULL | ff:ff:9d:5f:f5:03 | ...        | 152 |
+-----+----------------------------+-------------------+------------+-----+
```

In other words, this whole query attempts to get the first of each HardwareAddress in the given ordering.  The magic `FROM (SELECT @prev := '') init`?  That just initializes the SQL variable `@prev` for use within the ensuing subquery.  The tail `... ID DESC) x` part aliases the inner query to `x`.  One might utilize these aliases for further joins on more complicated queries, but in this case, they're there for MySQL syntax reasons.  You can ignore them.

All in all, a very inefficient method for getting the maximum ID associated with each HardwareAddress.  If the query needs the maximum of each column, then just ask directly with MAX.  Consider:

```
SELECT
  HardwareAddress,
  CONV(SUBSTRING(EventValue,3,2), 16, 10) AS 'Algorithm',
  MAX(ID) AS ID
FROM Events
WHERE
    Time > {unixtime}
AND EventType = 104
AND HardwareAddress IN ({disps})
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

You'll have an extra ID in your output; if the code is too brittle to deal with the new column, you can similarly mask it away as the original query did with a subselect:

```
SELECT HardwareAddress, CONV(...) AS 'Algorithm'
FROM (SELECT ...) x
```

Notwithstanding how selective `AND EventType` and `AND HardwareAddress` are, this should be a far more efficient query.  Even better if the `ID` column has an index.

Comment: Thank you! Answer accepted and bounty rewarded! I finally understand the query. Very well explained!

Answer (score 1):

All subqueries must be aliased. All the `init` subquery does is initialize the session/@ variable (it is equivalent to just executing `SET @prev := '';` before running the query).

Comment: That helps. Do you know what the `WHERE first` is doing?

Comment: It looks like it is grabbing only the first occurrence of each HardwareAddress.

Comment: But how? I'm unable to replicate the behavior when trying to make new queries using the `WHERE first` clause.

Comment: "first" is not a keyword, it is a field that is calculated in that subquery.

Comment: I see that it is a field, but there are no comparisons given for `first` in the WHERE clause. What is this WHERE clause doing and how does it work? Is this just saying, `WHERE first IS TRUE`?

Comment: Yes, first is effectively a boolean value.

Comment: @OnlyDean - `WHERE first IS TRUE` - actually it's saying: `WHERE first <> 0`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I'm afraid I don't understand what 'WHERE first <> 0' means either. Is that 'WHERE first is greater or less than 0?'

Comment: @OnlyDean `<>` is standard SQL for `!=` (not equal).

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM ( SELECT ... ) init
JOIN ( SELECT ... ) x
```

could be written

```
FROM ( SELECT ... ) AS init
JOIN ( SELECT ... ) AS x
```

This latter syntax helps imply that `init` and `x` are "aliases" for the subqueries.  Those aliases are *normally* needed elsewhere in the query, but not in this case, especially when there is an `ON` clause.  (Still, they are mandatory.)  The actual names used are not important.

```
SELECT @prev := ''
```

returns only one row; it is not really used.  It has the side effect of assigning the "user variable" `@prev` to the empty string.  The outer query depends on this subquery being performed before the other subquery.

BTW, the two subqueries are called "derived" tables since they are after `FROM` or `JOIN`.

```
SELECT HardwareAddress != @prev AS first,  -- Outputs 1 or 0
       @prev := HardwareAddress,           -- Outputs HA, and sets @prev
    ...
    ORDER BY
        HardwareAddress,                   -- to go thru in order
        ID DESC
```

will display `1` as `first` whenever there is a "change" in `HardwareAddress`  The intent is for `1` to be on the first line, then a bunch of lines with `0`, then back to `1` for a different addr.  These two expressions make a 'pattern' to achieve that goal.

```
HardwareAddress, EventValue, ID
```

finally, you can see `HardwareAddress` (and a couple of other things).

It would really be better to *format the output in your app code, not try to do the `@prev` game in SQL*.

```
WHERE first
```

Note that 0 means FALSE and anything else means TRUE.  `first` is an alias for the column discussed above.  So, when it is `1`, it displays; else it is skipped.

The effect is to show the 1st of each group, grouping by HardwareAddress.  By the way, this is not possible by a simple `GROUP BY`; some form of trickery is needed.  (See my discussion of [*groupwise max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) .)

```
SELECT
    HardwareAddress,
```

The second derived table necessarily has some extra columns.  Having this outer query lets you throw away those extras and focus on the desired output -- namely `HardwareAddress`, not `first`, not the extra copy of `HardwareAddress`.

```
SELECT ...
    CONV(SUBSTRING(EventValue,3,2), 16, 10) AS 'Algorithm'
```

This converts a portion of `EventValue` from hex to decimal.  The expression could have been done in the derived table; it does not make much difference.

```
, ID
```

This seems to be spurious info that is later thrown away.

```
              WHERE Time > {unixtime}
                AND EventType = 104
                AND HardwareAddress IN ({disps})
```

(I assume you understand the `WHERE` clause.)  I recommend the following to aid performance, especially if the table is large:

```
INDEX(EventType, Time),
INDEX(EventType, HardwareAddress)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This helped! I apologize that I could only award the bounty to one person.

Comment: @OnlyDean - He did a good job of explaining.  (But he left out the important indexes.)